# React Router DOM component not displayed when navigating to path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react project where I make use of React Router DOM to render different pages based on the visited URL.

All of the components render properly when I navigate to their respective URLs, except the Account component (when navigating to /admin/dashboard/table).

My routes are:

```
<Route path="/admin" element={<AdminLayout />}>
    <Route index path="home" element={<AdminHome />} />
    <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
        <Route path="table" element={<Account />} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

The Link to the /admin/dashboard/table URL is here:

```
<CardActionArea component={Link} to="table">
    <CardMedia
      component="img"
      height="300"
      image={cardImage}
      alt="green iguana"
    />
```

When clicking on the link, I successfully navigate to /admin/dashboard/table, but I do not understand why the Account component is not rendering when navigating to the URL.

Comment: do you mean manually typing the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean for the `Account` component to be rendered on nested route `"/admin/dashboard/table"` then the `DashBoard` component necessarily needs to render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes similar to what `AdminLayout` does.

Example:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...

    <Outlet />

    ...
  );
};
```

```
<Route path="/admin" element={<AdminLayout />}>
  <Route index path="home" element={<AdminHome />} />
  <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
    <Route path="table" element={<Account />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

This of course means that the `Dashboard` UI will be rendered at the same time as any of its nested route content.

If you meant for the `Account` component to be rendered discretely on it's own then you'll not want to nest it as a child of `Dashboard`, but rather as a sibling route.

Examples:

```
<Route path="/admin" element={<AdminLayout />}>
  <Route index path="home" element={<AdminHome />} />
  <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="dashboard/table" element={<Account />} />
</Route>
```

```
<Route path="/admin" element={<AdminLayout />}>
  <Route index path="home" element={<AdminHome />} />
  <Route path="dashboard">
    <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
    <Route path="table" element={<Account />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my error.

The Account page rendered properly, but because I nested it under the dashboard Route, it was not visible, due to the Dashboard component being on top of it.

I just had to edit my Routes as follows:

```
<Route path="/admin" element={<AdminLayout />}>
    <Route index path="home" element={<AdminHome />} />
    <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    <Route path="dashboard/table" element={<Account />} />
</Route>
```